# FTP - Change folder access by user connected

Tags: ftp, filezilla, user, privileges

I'm trying to block the access for some users to a certain folder to avoid the possibility of someone that isn't the administrator of the website changing the content or even deletes the content of some folders. For example, in this case I would to let a certain user the possibility of accessing just the `first_folder` :

```
public_html
    first_folder
    second_folder
    third_folder
```

It is possible to achieve this, or should I do something completely different?
Note that I'm using FileZilla to establish a connection, maybe I can get to my result changing a few settings in that software.

Comment: It's possible (at least on Unix systems) by changing owner and setting group private to to. What OS and FTP server?

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, if you create a FTP share, then you can set the user rights only per share, but not per subfolder. That is because the FTP server usually has no control over the shared content (files, subfolders).
You'd have to apply additional user rights e.g. from the operating system, but they cannot be combined with FTP, because all FTP users are given the OS user acoount rights under which the FTP server runs.
Conclusion: it's not possible in the way you try to do it. But you could for example create another FTP share, which targets the subfolder directly, and give it different user rights, which are those that you want for this subfolder.